# Single store mode problems

Tags: magento2

I recently activated single store mode, since it removes the need to select the scope everytime I want to edit a product.

Unfortunately it came with some problems, `"Content" -> "Configuration" -> "HTML Head"` is now empty. I checked the database and there are now 2 HTML head configurations:
[image]

`config_id` 31 is the HTML Head before activating **"single store mode"**, it is still the active one, I have to edit it in the database if I want to change it.

Comment: Hi, I am running into a similar issue. How did you fix? Which one did you remove?

Answer (score 4):

This may be related to an issue I just found.  Basically, if you enable single store mode after you have already modified you store, created categories, products, etc, the attribute values may be out of wack.  What seems to happen is that, while in multi-store mode (the default value), Magento sets the store_id of the values you change as "1" (or whatever your store was).  When you switch to single store mode, the store_id for all values is now "0".  This causes a conflict because, when it queries the DB for values, it asks for those where the store_id is either 0 or 1.  Depending on the order of the results, it may get the right value and then immediately overwrite itself with the wrong value as it loops through the result set to populate the data for the entity.  This causes much hair pulling and swearing (at least it did in my case).

To fix, all you have to do is delete all the values out of all the entity attribute tables where the store_id is not 0.  To do this, execute queries similar to this:

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_text WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_datetime WHERE store_id <> 0;

DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_int WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_text WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_decimal WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_datetime WHERE store_id <> 0;
```

There may be various other tables that need to be fixed in order for everything to work properly, this is not a complete list.  I was having trouble with categories being inactive even though they weren't.  As it turned out, I had activated them AFTER switching to single store mode, so it had 2 values in the tables, and the "0" overwrote the "1".  I also had some problems with some store configuration values (core_config_data).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi. I have already fixed it, just forgot that the question was still open. Another problem with single store mode is that you can't rearrange columns, you can't drag & drop columns like Name, SKU, Price and so on to where you want them. There is a GitHub issue created.

Comment: If you solved it, can you create your own answer and close the issue?  It's helpful to everyone if you can provide info about how you resolved something for anyone looking for this issue in the future.